# Why does every channel appear twice in my WiFi tool?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

My router (Linksys Velop Intelligent Mesh WiFi) seems to always duplicate every channel with a matching unnamed channel. When I use a WiFi tool, I see my channels as expected, but also for each one see a duplicate un-named channel with the same MAC address, channel, speed, and signal strength. In fact, I see the same for most of my neighbors' channels. What are those unnamed channels for. Why does every channel appear twice in my WiFi tool?

Comment: Is it perhaps a dual band router supporting 2.4GHz and 5GHz, so you are seeing both bands as separate?

Comment: @harrymc No it's by channel. So for example I have two entries for each combination of frequency band and channel. For example 5 Ghz Channel 149 has two entries that are exactly the same (including MAC address, signal strength, last seen, etc.) except one is named and the other isn't.

Comment: Remove all the local PC Wireless Profiles (NETSH WLAN command). Restart. Remove any duplicate router settings (I suggest a hard router reset and set up again).

Comment: @John So it's a local cash in my client? It appears for neighbors' routers too.

Comment: First question - yes delete extra profiles.   Second question - if external and more than one person sees it, do not check it, make sure it has not found its way to your local profiles and then just ignore it. Also change your own wireless SSID to something complex.

Comment: @John If you could spell that out in a bit more detail (for the network naive) and it included instructions on how to "delete extra profiles" on a Mac. I'd take it as an answer.